# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hi I am new to flutter firebase and I have an issue please:

I want to retrieve data from realtime database but I got a problem when usign StreamBuilder here is the code :

```
StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(stream: taskRef != null ? taskRef!.onValue : null, 
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError){
              var event = snapshot.data as DatabaseEvent;
              var snapshot2 = event.snapshot.value;
              if(snapshot2 == null) {
                return Center(child:Text("Pas de taches ajoutees"),);
              }

             Map<String, dynamic> map = snapshot2 as   Map<String, dynamic>;
              var tasks = <TaskModel>[];

              for(var taskMap in map.values){
                TaskModel taskModel = TaskModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>.from(taskMap));
                tasks.add(taskModel);
              }

              //return Center(child: Text(tasks.length.toString()),);
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(itemCount: tasks.length,itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  TaskModel task = tasks[index];
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10),

                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
                     ),
                    child: Column(
                      
                      children: [
                      
                      Text(task.taskName),
                      Text(getHumanReadableDate(task.dt)),

                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: () {},),
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit), onPressed: () {},),
                      ],)
                      
                    ],)
                  );
                }),
              );
            }  else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
          },)
```

please if you can help me about that error and thank you so much !

Comment: remove as   Map<String, dynamic> from line 
Map<String, dynamic> map = snapshot2 as   Map<String, dynamic>;

Comment: what response are you getting ?

Comment: okay I will try right now

Comment: I got this error in vs code: A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Comment: when I remove Map<String, dynamic> from line Map<String, dynamic> map = snapshot2 as Map<String, dynamic>;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for your response, finaly !! I have resolved the problem !

The problem was to use the type  Map<dynamic, dynamic> instead of  Map<String, dynamic> like that: Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot2 as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

And because that snapshot2 was a DatabaseEvent type.

so I got the data from the realtime database and everything goes well.

Thank you again.